# Spring Boot 2.0 Gradle run and test in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-security

I have a simple Spring Boot 2 application with Gradle as build system.
Everything runs fine as long as I use Gradle to run and test the project.

One controller class contain an `@Autowire`d bean

```
@Autowired
OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService
```

which works quite ok.

The problem is, when I try to run the application in IntelliJ IDEA through a right-click on the application class or if I start my test suite, the system complains that the above mentioned bean is missing.

Just referencing the bean without declaring it seems to be a standard pattern...

Any hint on where I could look for a solution?

Comment: Is it possible to provide sample project example?

Comment: sorry, I will try to come up with an example...

Answer (score 3):

I think problem cause is run configuration. 
You can run `gradle bootRun` by using IntelliJ. as below

Screen shot

[image]

Comment: yes, that works, but shouldn't it also run as simple application. I get the feeling that, if I run it through gradle, I lose some intellij features. Especially with tests...

Comment: I think I found the problem, but can't resolve it yet: it seems to be a misconfiguration of my IDE - the project settings don't have the Spring facet...

Comment: Do you can tell me what feature that lose when run with bootRun ?

Comment: with bootRun, it is just a feeling that I will run into problems for later deployments and the IDE will not support me as good as possible (it already tells me that it can't find the bean ni the editor).

Comment: with the tests, it is different. I lose the run, rerun etc. features of junit within the ide... So for me, this is something worth fixing... :-)

Answer (score 0):

so, I first thought that the problem is because of a misconfiguration in my project (it tells me that the bean definition is missing) but it seems to be a misconfiguration of IntelliJ which I couldn't verify yet:

When you go to the project settings (ALT+Shift+Ctrl+S), there is a facets section. The system should have autoconfigured some Spring facets, but these are not available on my system. This seems to be the reason of my problems.